# grouping sub-categories under a category sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these two tables

```
/* CAT TYPE */

id  name
1   Application
2   Brand
3   Feature


/* CATEGORIES */
id  name                url     description            type 
1   Temperature     temperature     A complete range ...    1 
2   Hobo            hobo            Hobo Loggers            2   
3   USB             usb             USB loggers         3   
4   Humidity    humidity    Humidity Loggers    1
```

And I want to display them in sections of each category under the Cat Type, in order of Cat Type id, and then order of Categories a-z.

So I want to do a sql query that will group all the above like this:

```
**Application**    
 - Temperature
 - Humidity

**Brand**    
 - Hobo

**Feature**    
 - USB
```

This is my current query

```
SELECT * FROM categories 
JOIN cat_type ON categories.type=cat_type.id
GROUP BY cat_type.id
```

But it is only grouping one category from each cat_type. I am not sure how to make it show all of them.

Comment: I think you need to order, not group. Replace `GROUP BY cat_type.id` to `ORDER BY cat_type.id, categories.name` in your query

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for an especific order, not a group. Try this:

```
SELECT cat_type.Name as 'Heading', categories.name as 'Name' FROM categories 
JOIN categories_type ON categories.type=cat_type.id
ORDER BY cat_type.id
```

Comment: Yes, I thought of that, but then how do I get the heading for each type?

Comment: @user2909486 Use `Heading` header in your presentation code.

Comment: @user2909486 Does it help? Would you accept the answer?